# Overriding Equals in Java - confused about implementation

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I've been doing the MOOC Java programming course and they typically override equals like this:

1. If addresses of the 2 objects are the same = return true.
2. If compared object is not an instance of the same class as the first object = return false.
3. Convert the object to the same type as the one being compared to
4. Compare the variables of each object - returns true or false

I'm just a bit confused about step 2 and 3.

- Step 2 checks if the 2nd object is an instance of the same type as the one its compared to...

---

If it isn't, the method ignores the rest of the code and returns false

If it is, we convert it to that Class. **So at this point i'm confused about why we need to convert an object that is already an instance of the same class - to that class?** If Java recognises it is of the same type, why do you need to convert it?

*Example below:

```
public boolean equals(Object comparedObject) { 
// if the variables are located in the same place, they're the same 
  if (this == comparedObject) { 
    return true; 
  }

// if comparedObject is not of type Book, the objects aren't the same **   
  if (!(comparedObject instanceof Book)) { 
    return false; 
  }
// convert the object to a Book object
Book comparedBook = (Book) comparedObject;**

// if the instance variables of the objects are the same, so are the objects
  if (this.name.equals(comparedBook.name) &&
    this.published == comparedBook.published &&
    this.content.equals(comparedBook.content)) {
    return true;
}

// otherwise, the objects aren't the same
return false;
}
```

Comment: Because the Java compiler does **not** know it is of the correct type. The runtime knows at that point but not the compiler.

Comment: The easiest way (for me): The compiler only knows about the declared reference type. The JVM at runtime knows what the object really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you’ve only compared the *dynamic* type; the *static* type of `comparedObject` is unchanged: it’s `Object`, and you cannot access its `Book` members (think about it: at this point *you* know that the dynamic type of `comparedObject` is `Book`; but the Java compiler still sees it with its declared type). To make the *compiler* understand that the object type is `Book`, you first need to create an object whose *static* type is `Book`, and to do that you need a cast.

The static type information is what the Java *compiler* sees, and which is what the compiler uses to check whether your code is statically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Java is statically typed, so if the variable is declared as `Object` it will not let you access any fields or call any methods of `Book`. In this case, it is easily proven that the object can only be a `Book`, but the compiler does not make any attempt to prove it. (And, in a [more complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591299/i-cant-explain-why-a-method-call-on-a-polymorphic-object-will-not-compile/71591691#71591691), it couldn't.)

In the newest versions of Java, there is a shortcut you can take with the syntax:

```
if (comparedObject instanceof Book book) {
    // do whatever with book
    return this.title.equals(book.title) && this.author.equals(book.author);
}
```

But in earlier versions, you simply have to downcast the instance:

```
if (comparedObject instanceof Book) {
    Book book = (Book) comparedObject;
    return this.title.equals(book.title) && this.author.equals(book.author);
}
```

Comment: note that using `instanceof` instead of comparing the class is not symmetric, breaking the [*contract*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) of `equals`: "*for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true*" - AFAIK there is no consensus on that: some state that `equals()` must use `instanceof` to *allow* subclass instances; other that it must be the same class, not accepting subclass instsances as equals